# Find location of elements in a list for multiple patterns in R

Tags: r, list, element

I have a list with character elements and I need the location of several patterns.
I need to extract it from the  `$tip.label`

I can do it for one pattern with

```
lapply(complete.tree, function(ch) grep("Scaptotrigona_tricolorata", ch))$tip.label
```

How can I do it for several different patterns?
I tried a loop

```
for (i in species) {
    x[i]= lapply(complete.tree, function(ch) grep("i", ch))$tip.label
}
```

where "species" is a vector with all the names I need

Any advice is appreciated!

Here is the list:

```
> str(complete.tree)
List of 5
 $ edge       : int [1:332, 1:2] 168 169 170 170 171 172 173 173 174 175 ...
 $ edge.length: num [1:332] 24.2 0 77.8 39.38 2.63 ...
 $ Nnode      : int 166
 $ node.label : chr [1:166] "54" "133" "135" "71" ...
 $ tip.label  : chr [1:167] "Bombus" "Scaptotrigona_polysticta" "Scaptotrigona_sp._B_CR-2009" "Scaptotrigona_sp._A_CR-2009" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "phylo"
 - attr(*, "order")= chr "cladewise"
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'complete.tree' is a `list` of `vectors`s.  Assuming that the OP wanted to match the 'tip.label', loop over the 'species' in `lapply`, `grep` that element on the extracted (`$`) 'tip.label' from 'complete.tree'

```
lapply(species, function(x) grep(x, complete.tree$tip.label))
```